# Check which targets/components a stack target/component depends on?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, intero

By running `stack ide targets`, I can get a list of all the targets in a stack project. For example, for [Halive](https://github.com/lukexi/halive), I get:

```
halive:lib
halive:exe:halive
halive:test:compileexpr
halive:test:demo
halive:test:subhalive
halive:test:testghc
halive:test:unit
```

I'd like to now if there's a way we can ask stack, intero, or some other tool, which targets a target depends on.

For example, in this scenario, I'd like stack/intero/whatever to tell me that `halive:test:unit` depends on `halive:lib`.

In case that's not possible, I guess I can try inspecting the .cabal file myself... is there a parser or a tool or something that could give me something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `stack dot` command to build dependency graph for your project and then analyze this graph by yourself. I think your task is rather specific. Just a single analyzing algorithm for dependency graph. Probably not so common so it's not implemented yet (maybe it's implemented, but I'm not aware of it).

See details here:

[Use “stack dot” to see which of your deps bring a particular package to your dependency tree](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskelltil/comments/6scuiu/use_stack_dot_to_see_which_of_your_deps_bring_a/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working the way I expected... https://gist.github.com/dcastro/05d1076e3cd134a1bc473f77e401998d

Comment: Hmm, you're right. This command doesn't show dependencies on internal modules :( Probably you can open feature request in `stack` repository for this.